# Can't upload screenshot for review for In-App Purchase in iTunes Connect

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I created an in-app purchase, and the only thing I need is to upload a screenshot. The problem is that every time I try to upload it, I choose the file, click save, it loads a bit and then the popup disappears with NO screenshot uploaded and no error message.

I have tried with a lot of images, all of which were at least 640x920 pixels and at least 72 DPI, like in the requirement. But it doesn't take, and I don't know what more to do.

Is there something that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem. The magic for me was being patient. After you select a file it actually starts to upload it in the background (even though it didn't show anything in the UI for me) so you have to wait for it to finish and show the thumbnail before clicking "Save". After I figured this out, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. In desperation I tried uploading in Chrome rather than Safari and it worked. I've never had a problem before but they have just redesigned the site so something's gone awry (maybe my content blockers were getting in the way).

Comment: As weird as this seems, this worked for me as well. Tried around 6 times in Safari and it never completed. Then, when trying in Chrome it worked on first attempt. By the way, for anyone struggling with this: Try to use the EXACT measurements (640x920 pixels,  PNG). Maybe this was a temporary issue, but anything larger (even at scale) did not work for me in the past.

Comment: You definitely have to upload the exact sizes they ask for in non-alpha PNGs (they don't do any resizing for you save for downscaling to older devices but you need iPhone 8 Plus and iPhone 11 Pro Max resolutions as a minimum)

Comment: It was the 640x920 pixels that did the trick for me.  Madness!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with agreeing to the lastest terms inside the developer portal (http://developer.apple.com) which prevented me somehow from changing/uploading/editing anything. I did not see a warning when I logged into iTunes Connect though, which was strange. (A lot of stuff is happening due to WWDC2020, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Even though the documentation says "at least" 640 x 920 pixels, I was able to solve it by uploading an image that was *exactly* 640 x 920 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used an iPhone 7 screenshot to fix the issue. The image extension does not matter whether it is **.jpeg** or **.png**.

Apple documentation specifies the following points.

1. iOS requires at least 640 x 920 pixels.
2. In the end, however, we must upload screenshots of the product we are selling rather than the In-App-Purchase popup or dialog.

As mentioned in Apple documentation.
For example, if it’s a book, you can submit a screenshot of the book image.

For more information please visit the given link: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev84b80958f

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's not the image resolution but the filename.

Screenshots generated by Simulator, for example, are named something along the lines of "Simulator Screenshot - iPad Air (5th generation) - 2023-10-11 at 17.20.33"

Rename that to "iap_1" or something, usually that does the trick for me (in case the resolution is in the list found here: [Screenshot specifications](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/screenshot-specifications)

I hope this helps!